# Open in-app browser to log in, get a cookie, and use the cookie in the app

Tags: ionic-framework, cookies, capacitor

I have a Capacitor Ionic React app (PWA/iOS/Android), and I have been using the [http plugin](https://github.com/capacitor-community/http) to log in to a Drupal 9 backend.

Recently, I added "Sign in with Apple" and "Log in with Google" support to Drupal 9 via Drupal's [OpenID Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect) module.

This is how the login flow works in Drupal:

1. Go to Drupal login page.
2. Click "Log in with Google."
3. Log in with your Google account.
4. Get redirected back to Drupal.
5. Drupal provides a session cookie for the logged-in Google account.

I want to use this same flow in Ionic/Capacitor.

So, I added the [Capacitor browser plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser), and used this plugin to create an in-app browser that goes to my login page.

Now, in my apps, I can use the in-app browser to log in to my Drupal site via Google and Apple.  However, the session cookie is in the in-app browser, and when I close the in-app browser, my Capacitor app does not have access to the in-app browser session cookie.

Is there a way to get access to in-app browser cookies from the native app that launched the in-app browser?

[This post in the capacitor forums](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/issues/7#issuecomment-736655197) suggests that it might not be possible, but I want to confirm: is there any way to use an in-app browser to log in to a website, get a session cookie, and then use that session cookie in a Capacitor / Ionic app?

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to achieve probably won't work. Using iOS as an example, the Capacitor Browser plugin uses `SFSafariViewController` under the hood. `SFSafariViewController` is essentially a Safari process, running outside of your app. So your app won't have access to the cookies used by the `SFSafariViewController`, just as your app has no access to the cookies in Safari.